# ¿Por qué no se modifica el código css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Tengo un mini-proyecto (práctica para ir agarrando la mano), el ejercicio es el que se especifica [aquí](https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas/blob/master/Projects/1-Beginner/Border-Radius-Previewer.md). A continuación les dejo todo el código (html, css y js) para que puedan tener un panorama completo de mi situación.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', inicio());

function inicio() {
    document.getElementById('range_tl').addEventListener('change', modifyBorderRadius);
    document.getElementById('range_tr').addEventListener('change', modifyBorderRadius);
    document.getElementById('range_br').addEventListener('change', modifyBorderRadius);
    document.getElementById('range_bl').addEventListener('change', modifyBorderRadius);
}

function modifyBorderRadius() {
    let container = document.getElementById('div_container__modifiable').style;
    let out_range = document.getElementsByTagName('output');

    container.borderTopLeftRadius = out_range[0].value;
    container.borderTopRightRadius = out_range[1].value;
    container.borderBottomRightRadius = out_range[2].value;
    container.borderBottomLeftRadius = out_range[3].value;
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
    margin: 10%;
    background-color: rgb(155, 151, 151);
}

.container__div--first {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    grid-column: 3 / span 4;
    grid-row: 3 / span 5;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.container__div--tl {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.container__div--tr {
    grid-column: 7 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    display: flex;
}

.container__div--br {
    grid-column: 7 / span 1;
    grid-row: 8 / span 1;
    display: flex;
}

.container__div--bl {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 8 / span 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

output {
    padding: 10px;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 8 / 9;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgb(77, 72, 72);
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9px;
}

button:active {
    transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgb(77, 72, 72);
}

input {
    cursor: pointer;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Border-radius Previewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container" id="div_container">
        <div class="container__div--first" id="div_container__modifiable">
            
        </div>
        <div class="container__div--tl">
            <input type="range" value="0" class="div__range" id="range_tl" list="tickmarks" onchange="document.getElementById('out_range_tl').value = value + '%'">
            <output id="out_range_tl" class="div_out" for="range_tl">0%</output>
        </div>
        <div class="container__div--tr">
            <input type="range" value="0" class="div__range" id="range_tr" list="tickmarks" onchange="document.getElementById('out_range_tr').value = value + '%'">
            <output id="out_range_tr" class="div_out" for="range_tr">0%</output>         
        </div>
        <div class="container__div--br">
            <input type="range" value="0" class="div__range" id="range_br" list="tickmarks" onchange="document.getElementById('out_range_br').value = value + '%'">
            <output id="out_range_br" class="div_out" for="range_br">0%</output>
        </div>
        <div class="container__div--bl">
            <input type="range" value="0" class="div__range" id="range_bl" list="tickmarks" onchange="document.getElementById('out_range_bl').value = value + '%'">
            <output id="out_range_bl" class="div_out" for="range_bl">0%</output>
            <datalist id="tickmarks">
                <option value="0"></option>
                <option value="10"></option>
                <option value="20"></option>
                <option value="30"></option>
                <option value="40"></option>
                <option value="50"></option>
                <option value="60"></option>
                <option value="70"></option>
                <option value="80"></option>
                <option value="90"></option>
                <option value="100"></option>
            </datalist>
        </div>
        <button id="btn_download"><a href="style.css" title="download css.txt" class="a_download">Download css code</a></button>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

La cuestión es que al darle al botón para ***descargar el código*** me redirige al archivo para darle a "guardar como" y proceder a descargarlo, pero si yo modifico los border-radius, ***dichos cambios no se ven reflejados en el código css***. Me gustaría saber como hacer para que se modifique o en su defecto, poder obtener el código resultante de los cambios de forma independiente del código original. Seguramente hay muchas cosas que se puedan mejorar, por eso estoy abierto a cualquier consejo/ayuda que me quieran dar.

Comment: No se modifica porque no interaccionas directamente con el stylesheet, sino con los propios valores del elemento. Ahora tendrías que crear un nuevo stylesheet volcando esos valores en él, y generar el enlace de descarga dinámicamente. 

Yo he estado haciendo pruebas y no tengo los conocimientos suficientes para poder darte una solución limpia y de calidad, pero seguro que este fiddle te ayuda a orientarte: https://jsfiddle.net/s5on5dau/1/ ;)

Comment: Prueva esto y dime si es lo que quieres descargar: `console.log( document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML);`. Eso te retornará toda la hoja de stylo usada, ahora que tal si le concatenas el stylo del elemento ya modificado`...innerHTML+="#div modificable{ border-top-left-radius:"+output.value+";border-....` Y haci hasta obtener todo el texto que deseas que el usuario descarge. Y [por ultimo generas el archivo con ese css y lo pasas al href](https://ourcodeworld.co/articulos/leer/189/como-crear-un-archivo-y-generar-descarga-con-javascript-en-el-navegador-sin-servidor)

Comment: Pero no se si se puede usando el elemento link para obtener el contenido del archivo: `style.css" desde javascript.

Comment: Descubri por experimentacion que puedes hacer esto: `var link=document.getElementsByTagName("link");
console.log(link.sheet.cssRules[0].style)`, pero tendras que hacer un esfuerso por filtrar mucha cosas que no nos interesan. Y adicionalmente puedes ver cual link es que estas usando recorriendo la lista de elementos link con un bucle y un `style=(link[i].getAttribute("href")==="style.css`)?link[i]:style;`

Answer (score 1):

El problema que veo es que no estas accediendo a el stylesheet ,te pongo un ejemplo:
En tu función:

```
 function modifyBorderRadius() {
let container = document.getElementById('div_container__modifiable').style;
let out_range = document.getElementsByTagName('output');

container.borderTopLeftRadius = out_range[0].value;
container.borderTopRightRadius = out_range[1].value;
container.borderBottomRightRadius = out_range[2].value;
container.borderBottomLeftRadius = out_range[3].value;
```

}

Actualizas valores CSS pero no estas haciendo ningún cambio en ninguna hoja de estilo , no se queda guardado .
Tendrías que acceder a la hoja de estilo , por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
 var style=document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0]
```

Y a partir de ahí ya podrás ver que los cambios se quedan guardados en la hoja de estilo .